# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).onChange is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am developing area calculator with width height and uint when i enter width and height it has to multiply and when ever i change the the unit that particular result has to come.
but when i enter width and height i am getting error like Uncaught TypeError: $(...).onChange is not a function
How can i solve this one?

Below is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <style>
      .tt-area-calculator-title {
        text-align: right;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #01acf1;
      }
      .tt-calculator-container {
        display: block;
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        height: 0;
      }
      .active {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        height: auto;
      }
      .areacalc {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 16px;
        border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
        background: #f8f8f8;
        color: #262626;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }
      .areacalc-column {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .areacalc-column-inner {
        padding: 0 0 5px;
      }
      .areacalc-label {
        color: #21293c;
        padding: 4px 0;
        font-weight: 600;
        text-transform: uppercase;
      }
      p {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0.9rem;
      }
      .areacalc-table-measurements {
        text-align: center;
      }
      table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        max-width: 100%;
      }
      tbody {
        display: table-row-group;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border-color: inherit;
      }
      .areacalc-table-measurements {
        text-align: center;
      }
      tr {
        display: table-row;
        vertical-align: inherit;
        border-color: inherit;
      }
      .areacalc-table-measurements {
        text-align: center;
      }
      .areacalc-column th {
        padding: 2px;
        font-weight: 400;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .areacalc-column td {
        padding: 2px;
      }
      .table-l {
        text-align: right;
        width: 50%;
      }

      .table-r {
        text-align: left;
        width: 50%;
        font-weight: 700;
      }
      .areacalc-input,
      select.areacalc-select {
        padding: 0 5px !important;
        height: 26px !important;
        border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
      }
      .cell-d {
        font-weight: 600;
        padding: 6px 0 !important;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="tt-area-calculator-title">
      <span class="tt-calculator-span"
        ><i class="fas fa-calculator"></i> Area Calculator</span
      >
    </div>
    <div
      id="tt-area-calculator-container"
      class="tt-calculator-container"
      data-bind="scope: 'area_calculator'"
    >
      <!-- ko template: getTemplate() -->
      <div class="areacalc">
        <!-- COLUMN 1 -->
        <div class="areacalc-column">
          <!-- AREA TO BE TILED -->
          <div class="areacalc-column-inner">
            <p class="areacalc-label" data-bind="i18n: 'Area(s) to be tiled'">
              Area(s) to be tiled
            </p>
            <table class="areacalc-table-measurements" style="width: 100%">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th style="width: 12%"></th>
                  <th style="width: 22%" data-bind="i18n: 'Width'">Width</th>
                  <th style="width: 22%" data-bind="i18n: 'Height'">Height</th>
                  <th style="width: 22%" data-bind="i18n: 'Unit'">Unit</th>
                  <th style="width: 22%" data-bind="i18n: 'Area'">Area</th>
                </tr>
                <!-- ko foreach: {data: $data.areaTiled, as: '$row' } -->
                <tr data-bind="css: {'_last': $row.isLast()}" class="_last">
                  <td class="cell-a">
                    <!-- ko if: $row.canDelete --><!-- /ko -->
                  </td>
                  <td class="cell-b">
                    <input
                      id="areaWidth"
                      class="areacalc-input"
                      type="text"
                      name="width"
                      data-bind="value: $row.width, valueUpdate: 'keyup'"
                    />
                  </td>
                  <td class="cell-c">
                    <input
                      id="areaHeight"
                      class="areacalc-input"
                      type="text"
                      name="height"
                      data-bind="value: $row.height, valueUpdate: 'keyup'"
                    />
                  </td>
                  <td class="cell-u">
                    <select
                      name="unit"
                      class="areacalc-select"
                      data-bind="options: $parent.unitsArray, value: selectedUnit"
                    >
                      <option value="m">m</option>
                      <option value="mm">mm</option>
                      <option value="cm">cm</option>
                      <option value="inches">inches</option>
                      <option value="feet">feet</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td class="cell-d">
                    <span id="total" data-bind="text: $row.square">0</span>
                    <span>m²</span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td style="font-weight: 600; padding: 6px 0px !important">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Total'">Total</span>
                    <span id="totalvalue" data-bind="text: $data.areaTiledTotal"
                      >0</span
                    >
                    <span>m²</span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>

            <!-- AREA TO BE DEDUCTED -->
            <p
              class="areacalc-label"
              data-bind="i18n: 'Area(s) to be deducted'"
            >
              Area(s) to be deducted
            </p>
            <table class="areacalc-table-measurements" style="width: 100%">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th style="width: 12%"></th>
                  <th style="width: 22%" data-bind="i18n: 'Width'">Width</th>
                  <th style="width: 22%" data-bind="i18n: 'Height'">Height</th>
                  <th style="width: 22%" data-bind="i18n: 'Unit'">Unit</th>
                  <th style="width: 22%" data-bind="i18n: 'Area'">Area</th>
                </tr>
                <!-- ko foreach: {data: $data.areaDeducted, as: '$row' } -->
                <tr data-bind="css: {'_last': $row.isLast()}" class="_last">
                  <td class="cell-a">
                    <!-- ko if: $row.canDelete --><!-- /ko -->
                  </td>
                  <td class="cell-b">
                    <input
                      id="areaWidth1"
                      class="areacalc-input"
                      type="text"
                      name="width"
                      data-bind="value: $row.width, valueUpdate: 'keyup'"
                    />
                  </td>
                  <td class="cell-c">
                    <input
                      id="areaHeight1"
                      class="areacalc-input"
                      type="text"
                      name="height"
                      data-bind="value: $row.height, valueUpdate: 'keyup'"
                    />
                  </td>
                  <td class="cell-u">
                    <select
                      name="unit"
                      class="areacalc-select"
                      data-bind="options: $parent.unitsArray, value: selectedUnit"
                    >
                      <option value="m">m</option>
                      <option value="mm">mm</option>
                      <option value="cm">cm</option>
                      <option value="inches">inches</option>
                      <option value="feet">feet</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td class="cell-d">
                    <span id="total1" data-bind="text: $row.square">0</span>
                    <span>m²</span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td style="font-weight: 600; padding: 6px 0px !important">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Total'">Total</span>
                    <span
                      id="totalvalue1"
                      data-bind="text: $data.areaDeductedTotal"
                      >0</span
                    >
                    <span>m²</span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- COLUMN 2 -->
        <div class="areacalc-column">
          <div class="areacalc-column-inner">
            <p class="areacalc-label">You will need</p>
            <table class="areacalc-table-results" style="width: 100%">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="table-l">Total area:</td>
                  <td class="table-r">
                    <span data-bind="text: $data.areaTotal">0</span>
                    <span>m²</span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="table-l">Tiles required:</td>
                  <td class="table-r" data-bind="text: $data.tilesRequired">
                    0
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="table-l"></td>
                  <td class="table-r"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="table-l">Est. Grout required:</td>
                  <td class="table-r">
                    <span data-bind="text: $data.groutBags">0</span>
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'x 3kg bag(s)'">x 3kg bag(s)</span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="table-l">Est. Adhesive required:</td>
                  <td class="table-r">
                    <span data-bind="text: $data.adhesiveBags">0</span>
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'bag(s)'">bag(s)</span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="table-l">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Add'">Add</span>
                    <span data-bind="text: $data.waste + '%'">10%</span>
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'for wastage?'">for wastage?</span>
                  </td>
                  <td class="table-r">
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      style="float: left; margin-right: 5px"
                      data-bind="checked: $data.isWasteEnabled"
                    />
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".tt-area-calculator-title").click(function () {
          $(".tt-calculator-container").toggleClass("active");
        });
      });
      $("#areaWidth,#areaHeight").keyup(function () {
        var textValue1 = $("#areaWidth").val();
        var textValue2 = $("#areaHeight").val();
        var total = textValue1 * textValue2;
        var measurement = document.querySelector(".areacalc-select").value;
        console.log(measurement);
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $(".areacalc-select").onChange(function () {
            if (measurement === "m") {
              return total;
              document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
              document.getElementById("totalvalue").innerHTML = total;
            } else if (measurement === "mm") {
              document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total * 3;
              document.getElementById("totalvalue").innerHTML = total * 3;
            } else if (measurement === "cm") {
              document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total * 4;
              document.getElementById("totalvalue").innerHTML = total * 4;
            } else if (measurement === "inches") {
              document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total * 5;
              document.getElementById("totalvalue").innerHTML = total * 5;
            } else {
              document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total * 6;
              document.getElementById("totalvalue").innerHTML = total * 6;
            }
          });
        });
      });
      $("#areaWidth1,#areaHeight1").keyup(function () {
        var textValue1 = $("#areaWidth1").val();
        var textValue2 = $("#areaHeight1").val();
        var total = textValue1 * textValue2;
        document.getElementById("total1").innerHTML = total;
        document.getElementById("totalvalue1").innerHTML = total;
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

For reference please find the attached image also.
[image]

Comment: Document ready and change events inside a keyup or click event is incorrect to use. Instead, all the click, change and keyup or any other events is ideal to be inside one document ready handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax should be `$(".areacalc-select").on("change", function () {`

Answer (score 1):

You should replace `$(".areacalc-select").onChange(function () {`  with the [**on**](https://api.jquery.com/on/) function. In **jQuery** onChange doens't exists.

in your case it will look like this

```
$(".areacalc-select").on('change', function () {
    // Your code goes here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using wrong syntax to bind the event to the .areacal-select element. their is no function called onChange in jquery, that is why you are getting an exception saying it is not a function.

the correct way is to using something like $(selector).on("change", function(){})

here is you updated code that should work for you

```
      $(".areacalc-select").on("change", function () {
        if (measurement === "m") {
          return total;
          document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
          document.getElementById("totalvalue").innerHTML = total;
        } else if (measurement === "mm") {
          document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total * 3;
          document.getElementById("totalvalue").innerHTML = total * 3;
        } else if (measurement === "cm") {
          document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total * 4;
          document.getElementById("totalvalue").innerHTML = total * 4;
        } else if (measurement === "inches") {
          document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total * 5;
          document.getElementById("totalvalue").innerHTML = total * 5;
        } else {
          document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total * 6;
          document.getElementById("totalvalue").innerHTML = total * 6;
        }
      });
```